# Tabbar with storyboard

Tags: ios5, uitabbarcontroller, xcode4.2, storyboard

I have project with storyboard that start with viewController to login, when the user login the app changed to tabbar, tha rootView is the viewController no the tabbar.
My problem is that i want to implement the method "tabbar didselectviewcontroller" or "tabbar didselectitem" but i cant't do that in AppDelegate because i don't know how to create UITabarController and connect him to the tabBar on the IB, if i create property tabBar i can't see him anywhere in IB.
Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question correctly, you need a way to get the tabbar created from storyboard.

Try this:

```
[(UITabBarController*)self.window.rootViewController tabBar]
```

because the rootView is the `UITabBarController actually`, just with a reference with the viewController handle type.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly this is how I would it it:
add a Tabbarview controller in the storyboard, then in your first view implement a method where when user is succesfully logged in it loads the tabbarviewcontroller (modal transition)
then create class files for the tabbar controller and with that class you should be abale to implement didselectviewcontroller (you should include the UITabbarcontrollerdelagate in you header interface I believe)
hope it helps

Answer (score -1):

I don't exactly understand what your problem is. Did you have a look at [the apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/UsingViewControllersinYourApplication/UsingViewControllersinYourApplication.html) or the explanation [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5138/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-1)?

Comment: Yes, i read them but i dont see answer, i need to know how can i create  UITabarController and connect him to the tabbar that exist on storyboard.

Comment: -1 the "explanation link" makes no mention of the tababr didselectitem delegate.